# Cant get the getUrl() in to onBindViewHolder?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a `ListSourceAdapter.java` class,

```
class ListSourceViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    ItemClickListener itemClickListener;
    TextView source_title;
    CircleImageView source_image;

    public ListSourceViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        source_title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.source_name);
        source_image = (CircleImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.source_image);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        itemClickListener.onClick(v, getAdapterPosition(), false);
    }
}

public class ListSourceAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListSourceViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private WebSite webSite;

    public ListSourceAdapter(Context context, WebSite webSite) {
        this.context = context;
        this.webSite = webSite;
    }

    @Override
    public ListSourceViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.source_layout, parent, false);

        return new ListSourceViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ListSourceViewHolder holder, int position) {

        StringBuilder iconBetterAPI = new StringBuilder("https://icons.better-idea.org/allicons.json?url=");
        iconBetterAPI.append(webSite.getSources().get(position).getUrl());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return webSite.getSources().size();
    }
}
```

in `onBindView` Im try to use `getUrl()` but it says cannot resolve method

my `WebSite.java` model class like below

```
public class WebSite {

    private String status;
    private List<Source> sources;

    public WebSite() {
    }

    public WebSite(String status, List<Source> sources) {
        this.status = status;
        this.sources = sources;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public List<Source> getSources() {
        return sources;
    }

    public void setSources(List<Source> sources) {
        this.sources = sources;
    }
}
```

`Source.java` file like below

```
class UrlsToLogs {

    private String small, medium, large;

    public String getSmall() {
        return small;
    }

    public void setSmall(String small) {
        this.small = small;
    }

    public String getMedium() {
        return medium;
    }

    public void setMedium(String medium) {
        this.medium = medium;
    }

    public String getLarge() {
        return large;
    }

    public void setLarge(String large) {
        this.large = large;
    }
}

public class Source {

    private String id, name, description, url, category, language, country;
    private UrlsToLogs urlsToLogs;
    private List<String> sortByAvailable;

    public Source() {

    }

    public Source(String id, String name, String description, String url, String category, String language, String country, UrlsToLogs urlsToLogs, List<String> sortByAvailable) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.url = url;
        this.category = category;
        this.language = language;
        this.country = country;
        this.urlsToLogs = urlsToLogs;
        this.sortByAvailable = sortByAvailable;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public String getLanguage() {
        return language;
    }

    public void setLanguage(String language) {
        this.language = language;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public UrlsToLogs getUrlsToLogs() {
        return urlsToLogs;
    }

    public void setUrlsToLogs(UrlsToLogs urlsToLogs) {
        this.urlsToLogs = urlsToLogs;
    }

    public List<String> getSortByAvailable() {
        return sortByAvailable;
    }

    public void setSortByAvailable(List<String> sortByAvailable) {
        this.sortByAvailable = sortByAvailable;
    }
}
```

`IconBetterIdeaService` interface like below

```
public interface IconBetterIdeaService {

    @GET
    Call<IconBetterIdea> getIconUrl(@Url String url);

}
```

`ItemClickListner` interface like below

```
public interface ItemClickListener {

    void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick);
}
```

why I can't access `getUrl()`, what did I do wrong in my code?

[image]

Comment: did you create separate class becase it woking fine in my studio

Comment: yeah all above as I said in separate classes

Comment: its working fine in my studio

Comment: Error:(62, 64) error: cannot find symbol method getUrl() Im getting this error can you tell me why

Comment: Didn't see any problem in your code, try clean and rebuild. Or  check your import statements!

Comment: @HemalHerath try to create that class seperate

Comment: I added an image my error

Comment: @HemalHerath  your code working fine in my device

Comment: whats your android version

Comment: @HemalHerath i have creates separate class in android-studio 2.3.3 and its woking

Comment: Check the import of `Source` because it might a different class.

Comment: I have created a separate classes and checked import statements but still not working Im using android 3.0.1

Comment: Aside from `getUrl` can you call other method like `getCategory`, `getLanguage` and `getCountry`?

Comment: nop I cant @Enzokie

Comment: My only theory is that the `Source` in this line `private List<Source> sources;` is not the Pojo you made, it is possible that you imported `javax.xml.transform.Source` by accident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this create separate class like this

```
public class WebSite {

    private String status;
    private List<Source> sources;

    public WebSite() {
    }

    public WebSite(String status, List<Source> sources) {
        this.status = status;
        this.sources = sources;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public List<Source> getSources() {
        return sources;
    }

    public void setSources(List<Source> sources) {
        this.sources = sources;
    }
}
```

than

```
public class Source {

    private String id, name, description, url, category, language, country;
    private UrlsToLogs urlsToLogs;
    private List<String> sortByAvailable;

    public Source() {

    }

    public Source(String id, String name, String description, String url, String category, String language, String country, UrlsToLogs urlsToLogs, List<String> sortByAvailable) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.url = url;
        this.category = category;
        this.language = language;
        this.country = country;
        this.urlsToLogs = urlsToLogs;
        this.sortByAvailable = sortByAvailable;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public String getLanguage() {
        return language;
    }

    public void setLanguage(String language) {
        this.language = language;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public UrlsToLogs getUrlsToLogs() {
        return urlsToLogs;
    }

    public void setUrlsToLogs(UrlsToLogs urlsToLogs) {
        this.urlsToLogs = urlsToLogs;
    }

    public List<String> getSortByAvailable() {
        return sortByAvailable;
    }

    public void setSortByAvailable(List<String> sortByAvailable) {
        this.sortByAvailable = sortByAvailable;
    }
}
```

than

```
public class UrlsToLogs {
    private String small, medium, large;

    public String getSmall() {
        return small;
    }

    public void setSmall(String small) {
        this.small = small;
    }

    public String getMedium() {
        return medium;
    }

    public void setMedium(String medium) {
        this.medium = medium;
    }

    public String getLarge() {
        return large;
    }

    public void setLarge(String large) {
        this.large = large;
    }

}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

> **Clear-Rebuild** and also check the imports

Comment: @HemalHerath  try **Clear-Rebiuld** and also check the imports

Comment: Thanks man I restart the pc now its working :-( Im sorry for the trouble

Comment: @HemalHerath happy to help u